# Atom: Where is the list with all the default snippets?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Or do I just have to manually type in each letter to see what it could be tabbed into? And change the file extension to see the language-specific snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about all of the snippets but for single languages, at a time you can go into **Settings \ Packages** and search for the language that you want. Then once you have found it scroll down until you find the snippets section and voilà, there are your snippets.

I know this is 7 months too late, but I just thought I would answer in case anyone else came looking for an answer like I did. :D

**Edit:** Just remembered something else, you can type *snippets available* in the command palette and see all the snippets for the file type you are focused on.